# R file won't knit, saying readxl package doesn't exist

Tags: r, rstudio, readxl

I'm using RStudio, and trying to knit my file to hand in my assignment. I installed the package "readxl" to read in a couple of excel files, and it worked fine in the actual coding of the assignment. But when I go to knit the file, I keep getting the error:

```
Error in library(readxl) : there is no package called 'readxl'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> 
library
Execution halted
```

This is the code in question:

```
install.packages("tidyverse",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("readxl",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(readxl)
```

This has been frustrating me for over an hour and I just can't fix it. I can see the readxl package to the right of the console, in the "packages" tab. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Has `readxl` been successfully installed? When you do `library(readxl)` are there any errors? Does `readxl` show up in `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Yes to every question. Package installed successfully, library correctly attached. readxl comes up in the "other packages" section of sessionInfo()

Comment: I've seen this happen after updating packages in RStudio without restarting the session. Try restarting RStudio?

Comment: I generally wouldn't include `install.packages()` calls in an Rmarkdown document - no need to reinstall the package every time you knit the document. Have you tried removing the `install.packages` calls?

Comment: Restarting Rstudio did not fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: Even without the install.packages lines the file does not knit, still getting the error message:

Comment: Try printing `.libPaths()` both in your RStudio session and in the document.  It may be that `readxl` was installed to a different path than the session that does the knitting is using.  This can happen if you don't have write permission on the regular R library.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Printing ```.libPaths()``` unfortunately doesn't help.